# Ngrok connections line meaning

Tags: networking, ssh

I have just set up ngrok, and read through the parts of the documentation pertaining to ssh, which is what I am using it for.

On the "host" or "server" device (not sure of the correct name), it shows a text UI, with a line for "Connections", with multiple columns. The columns are labelled "ttl" "opn" "rt1" "rt5" "p50" and "p90". There are numbers under each, which change occasionally.

I wish to know what each of the columns mean, as I have made many searches for "ngrok" and the labels, but nothing conclusive has come up in terms of their meanings.

Can anyone tell me what each of the labels mean?

(copied from stack overflow at a commenters request, please tell me if I'm in the wrong spot)

Update: When pulling the info from the API, some of the labels have longer names: "metrics":{"conns":{"count":79,"gauge":0,"rate1":2.457246109955258e-7,"rate5":0.00038372479383272124,"rate15":0.0008963016058921416,"p50":213239525,"p90":312309088089,"p95":596862711946,"p99":925411600728

With the longer names, some become more clear, like count and rate. But I'm still confused on what the numbers mean. Perhaps percentiles?

If anyone has any info that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote ngrok's customer service email about this, and here's what I got back:

> I don't have answers for all of these stats but I believe "ttl" is
> total connections through the tunnel, "opn" would be currently open
> connections, and "p50"/"p90" are likely the 50th and 90th percentile
> round-trip request times in seconds. I'm not sure what the "rt1"/"rt5"
> numbers are but I think they are the connection rate over the last 1
> minute and last 5 minutes respectively.
>
> The web status UI is a little
> bit clearer: http://localhost:4040/status

I looked at the web status UI and it does have clearer labels on it; that will probably be easier to figure out.

Comment: Thank you so much! obviously a little late, but I appreciate the info.

Answer (score 0):

I have never been able to find documentation for these status's myself however if you browse to http://localhost:4040 on the machine where you have established the tunnel you will access the Ngrok client API where these status's are displayed in a real-time web UI.

They are essentially statistics on the Connections, Connections Duration, HTTP Requests and HTTP Request Durations.

Comment: Obviously not exactly what I was looking for and if someone else gives a better answer I’ll except that, but this is good enough for now. Let me know if accepting this is the wrong thing to do.